# Warning message using glmer and mixed

Tags: r, lmer

I have a question about warning message when using glmer or mixed model in R. When I'm running these functions I get the following warning message:

```
Advarselsbesked:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00273462 (tol = 0.001, component 7)
```

Can anyone tell me if I should ignore this massage? And if not, what can I do to fix it?

Nick

Comment: No, you should not ignor this warning. More advice needs more information from you.

Comment: https://rpubs.com/bbolker/lme4trouble1 .  Can you tell us any more about your problem?

Comment: I can show you the function:

glmmresult1 <- glmer(Use.avavilable ~ Heightoftree + Treetype + (1 | Ind_Site), data = data_glmm, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

Do I need more definitions in the function?